# How do you plot a linear regression line?

Tags: r

How does one fit a linear regression line to a scatter plot using base R? Assuming you already have the summary info from the linear model.

I already have a scatter plot that compares `a` and `ix`, and I am trying to add the regression lines `lm.a` and `lm.b` to the plot. Should I use an a b line or something else?

```
a <- c(21, 23, 25, 27, 29)
ix <- c(100, 300, 500, 600, 750)
ib <- c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1)
x <- data.frame(a, ix, ib)

lm.a <- with(x, lm(a ~ ix + ib + ix*ib))
summary(lm.a)
n1 <- lm.a$coefficients[1]
n2 <- lm.a$coefficients[2]
n3 <- lm.a$coefficients[3]
n4 <- lm.a$coefficients[4]
```

Comment: (1) Can we have a [mcve] please? (2) Do you have the fitted model object  or just the coefficients? (3) You seem to be fitting  models with two different predictor variables. What is on your scatter plot? Is one of the predictors categorical?

Comment: I doubt you can draw that regression line with `abline`. As @Allan Cameron suggested taking a closer look at your model it seems that you are looking to draw a *"regression plane"*, not a regression line. On the other hand you could just draw multiple regression lines. Could you detail your question a bit more?

Comment: like so "lm.a<- with(x, lm(a ~ ix + ib + exper*ib))
summary(lm.a)
b1 <- lm.a$coefficients[1]
b2 <- lm.a$coefficients[2]
b3 <- lm.a$coefficients[3]
b4 <- lm.a$coefficients[4]
abline(a=b1 +b2. b=b3+b4)
lm and a are continuous while ib is binary

Comment: @BenBolker  I just added what I assume is reproduceable code to the question and the comment above

Comment: This is better (voted to reopen); it's clearer, but it's not reproducible. We need code that will let us create `x`. Also: did you mean `a ~ ix + ib + ix*ib` ??

Comment: Please bring in your edits from your [newer post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65173571/how-do-i-plot-a-regression-line-from-this-data-set-and-formula-i-cannot-use-pac) and incorporate them into this question.

Comment: Is this adequate for the data frame of x? Is there anything more I should add to hopefully get this reopened? I really appreciate the help, because I am so new! Plus I hope this will help you all help me!

Comment: Yes, I think this should be sufficient.

Comment: `pairs(x)` will produce a scatterplot  between every pair of variables in `x`. or if you want a regression line through each `pnl <- function(x, y) { points(x, y); abline( lm(y ~ x)) };
pairs(x, panel = pnl)`

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it, here is a working example you can adapt:

```
height <- c(176, 154, 138, 196, 132, 176, 181, 169, 150, 175)
bodymass <- c(82, 49, 53, 112, 47, 69, 77, 71, 62, 78)

plot(bodymass, height)+
  abline(lm(height ~ bodymass)) # Missing lm here
```

[image]

Comment: This is certainly a good way to do it with one predictor and one outcome variable. I guess the problem is that in the example there appear to be two independent variables, so a scatterplot would have to be 3 dimensional, and the regression "line" would actually be a plane.

Comment: I added what I hope is clarifying code to the question itself, if that leads to a different answer